# Google Sheets Query returning odd formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a simple sheet to try to track and format race results from a league that I've joined. For the most part I know how I want to do this but when I use a query it's dropping data in some situations and formatting it strangely in others.
It seems as if where there are more numbers in a column than text it drops all text entries.
In addition for some reason when I add a check row, if it's included in the query it pushes almost all the data into a single cell except for the check row.

Would someone mind having a look and trying to figure out why it's doing this. Link Below
On sheet RRL1 I have my compiled data on the left, my 'missing' data on the right and my weirdly formatted data below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9xlQG06dQCrpMk3UMAX29oTlpRuhTfx6btbYTGmC8g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The `query()` formula will only support one data type per column — number, text, boolean or date. The type is determined by the majority of the values in the first few hundred rows. Values that are of another type will be returned as `null`, i.e., blank values.

> `=QUERY('Tournament Details'!D2:E22)`

Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) like this:

`={ 'Tournament Details'!D2:E22 }`

> `=TRANSPOSE(query('Tournament Details'!I3:I26))`

Use this:

`=transpose('Tournament Details'!I3:I26)`

Use this pattern to replace "DNS" and "DNF" with nulls:

```excel
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 'RRL1'!A1:C, iferror(value('RRL1'!D1:D)) }, 
    "select Col3, sum(Col4) 
     where Col3 is not null 
     group by Col3 
     label sum(Col4) 'Total AUS RRL1' ", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

The "squished" values you mention come about because you are not specifying the `headers` parameter. The best practice is to always include it, like this:

`=query('Tournament Details'!A2:E22,"select A where C != 'N/A'", 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, that explains the behaviour with the gaps although the squished data is still a mystery (with the check row)
Unfortunately the Array function won't allow me to drill down the data like I'm planning to do with the query. Is there any way to force the query to return everything as text?